# Ifelse multiple conditions

Tags: r

I'm new in R so don't be hard on me, I'm trying to make a loop with ifelse in R, I have the next code:

```
    x1=c(9.9,10.1,10.28,10.47,10.66,10.9,11.1,11.3,11.5)

    new1 = ((0.8822*x1)- 9.6887)

    x2=c(9.9,10.1,10.28,10.47,10.66,10.9,11.1,11.3,11.5)

    new2 = ((0.8822*x2)- 10.2887)

    cdata = mydata

    cd1= ifelse(new2 <= cdata <= new1,1.5,2)

    Error: unexpected '<=' in "cd1= ifelse(new2 <= cdata <="
```

And I don't know if there's another option to make it work

Answer (score 0):

With `mydata` undefined, I can't replicate the problem you are having. Also, your goal is not quite clear; what happens if new2 < new1 but cdata > new1?

The best I can do is the following code, which is equivalent to  "if new2 is <= both cdata and new1, and also cdata <= new1, return the value 1.5, else return the value 2":

```
ifelse((new2 <= cdata) & (new2 <= new1) & (cdata <= new1), 1.5, 2)
```

Comment: `new2 <= new1` is unnecessary - if the other two conditions are true that one **must** be true.